# Some users receive untrusted SSL certificate warnings

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I've been getting reports of users visiting our site getting "this certificate is not trusted" errors when visiting our site via https. I don't seem to ever have any problems, but two separate people on my team have gotten this error randomly when they're on a different wifi network other than the one at our office. They don't have the same problem at the office.

I read up on intermediate certificates but this seems to be just a browser thing, not a network related issue.

I have an SSL cert from GoDaddy, it's on a Rails app running on nginx + unicorn.

Does anyone have any other ideas why this might happen? I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that everyone is using the same host name.

I've seen this issue if there are multiple server aliases, for example www.foo.com and foo.com. be sure the one without the SSL certificate is redirecting traffic.

From home someone was using a different hostname, because of browser history. Fixing up the redirects fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be tied to your browser not trusting the intermediate cert and not related to wifi.  Please make sure the browser trusts the intermediate and root ca trust of GoDaddy.